# Iterate through dates to calculate difference

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am working with the following df:

```
              date/time wind (°) wind (kt) temp (C°) humidity(%) currents (°) currents (kt) stemp (C°) stemp_diff
0   2017-04-27 11:21:54    180.0      14.0      27.0      5000.0        200.0           0.4       25.4        2.6
1   2017-05-04 20:31:12    150.0      15.0      22.0      5000.0         30.0           0.2       26.5       -1.2
2   2017-05-08 05:00:52    110.0       6.0      25.0      5000.0         30.0           0.2       27.0       -1.7
3   2017-05-09 05:00:55    160.0      13.0      23.0      5000.0         30.0           0.6       27.0       -2.0
4   2017-05-10 16:39:16    160.0      20.0      22.0      5000.0         30.0           0.6       26.5       -1.8
5                   ...      ...       ...       ...         ...          ...           ...        ...        ...
6   2020-10-25 00:00:00   5000.0    5000.0      21.0        81.0       5000.0        5000.0       23.0       -2.0
7   2020-10-26 00:00:00   5000.0    5000.0      21.0        77.0       5000.0        5000.0       23.0       -2.0
8   2020-10-27 00:00:00   5000.0    5000.0      21.0        80.0       5000.0        5000.0       23.0       -2.0
9   2020-10-31 00:00:00   5000.0    5000.0      22.0        79.0       5000.0        5000.0       23.0       -2.0
10  2020-11-01 00:00:00   5000.0    5000.0      19.0        82.0       5000.0        5000.0       23.0       -2.0
```

I would like to find a way to iterate through the years and months my `date/time` column (i.e. April 2017, all the way to November 2020), and for each unique time period, calculate the average difference for the `stemp` column as a starting point (so the average for April 2017, May 2017, and so on, or even just use the months).

I'm trying to use this sort of code, but not quite sure how to translate it into something that works:

```
for '%MM' in australia_in['date/time']:
    australia_in['stemp_diff'] = australia_in['stemp (C°)'] - australia_out['stemp (C°)'] 
    australia_in
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first make sure that your `date/time` columns is of `datetime` type, and set it to index:

```
df['date/time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date/time'])
df = df.set_index('date/time')
```

Then you have several options.

Using [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))['stemp (C°)'].mean().dropna()
date/time
2017-04-30    25.40
2017-05-31    26.75
2020-10-31    23.00
2020-11-30    23.00
Name: stemp (C°), dtype: float64
```

Using the year and month:

```
>>> df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])['stemp (C°)'].mean()
date/time  date/time
2017       4            25.40
           5            26.75
2020       10           23.00
           11           23.00
Name: stemp (C°), dtype: float64
```

If you do not want to have the date/time as index, you can use the column instead:

```
df.groupby([df['date/time'].dt.year, df['date/time'].dt.month])['stemp (C°)'].mean()
```

And finally, to have nice names for the year and month:

```
(df.groupby([df['date/time'].dt.year.rename('year'),
             df['date/time'].dt.month.rename('month')])
   ['stemp (C°)'].mean()
)


output:
year  month
2017  4        25.40
      5        26.75
2020  10       23.00
      11       23.00
Name: stemp (C°), dtype: float64
```

Applying the same calculation on `stemp_diff`:

```
year  month
2017  4        2.600
      5       -1.675
2020  10      -2.000
      11      -2.000
Name: stemp_diff, dtype: float64
```

Comment: These are excellent suggestions which I am trying to implement, but I get a KeyError: 'date/time'

It seems as though the hh:mm:ss is an obstacle, so I have tried this:

australia_out['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(australia_out['date/time']).year
australia_out['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(australia_out['date/time']).month
australia_out

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: My ideal output would consist of a column which contains each unique year and month (i.e. 2017/04), and then next to each one, the average difference in stemp. So for example, April 2017 would have an average difference of 2, May 2017 of 5.6, and so on all the way until November 2020. Hope that helps!

Comment: What do you mean by "average difference"? The variance per year+month? If so, replace `mean` by `var`. If not, please provide a formula.

Comment: What I mean by average difference is that I calculate the difference across two dataframes for the sea temperature throughout all the days and years. Then after that, I would take all the relevant figures for January for example, and then find the average difference (so -2.5 + 3.6 + 4 for example, divided by the number of January's). Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok what you describe is the `mean`. It looks like you want to apply your calculation to the `stemp_diff` column, not `stemp (C°)`, but as I don't have tee full dataset it is difficult to be sure.

Comment: Can you check if the last block is what you expect (the actual values might be different as I only have a partial dataset)

Comment: @SamColeman did you eventually manage to do what you wanted to? Can you give some feedback?